# Selection not working after filter event in datatable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using primefaces datatable which has both filter and radio button for row select.

```xml
<p:dataTable id="dtId" var="bVar" widgetVar="dtWVar"
  value="#{bBean.myList}" filteredValue="#{bBean.bfilter}"
  rowKey="#{bVar.Id}" selection="#{bBean.selectedObj}">
  <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bBean.onFilter()}" />

  <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"
      actionListener="#{bBean.onSelectRadio()}" />
  <p:column selectionMode="single" headerText="RadioColHeader">
</p:dataTable>
```

On selecting the radio button the value is getting set in `selectedObj` but it stops working after we datatable filter is used. The radio button gets selected but the selected object is not getting set in `selectedObj`.

Please suggest a way to get the selected row value into the selection object even after filter event is triggered.

Comment: Version info please and [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje We are using primefaces 5.1.9 Will come up with minimul working code in some time.

Comment: And in the mean time, try a newer version and check the issuelist...

Comment: If something JS related has worked and then stops working, you might find errors in your browser's JS console.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :) , i have posted the issue fix as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed on invoking `process="@this"` in ajax filter event and then updating the data table through remote command as below:

Ajax event - inside the datatable

`<p:ajax event="filter" process="@this" listener="#{bBean.onFilter()}" oncomplete="updateDataTable();" />`

Remote command - outside the datatable

`<p:remoteCommand name="updateDataTable" update="dtId" />`